# NUnit not working on teamcity agent in docker

Tags: nunit, teamcity

I am running teamcity server and agent in a docker container (https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2016/06/teamcity-on-docker-hub-its-official-now/). I am trying to build dotnet core application. I have 3 build steps as "dotnet restore", "dotnet build" and "dotnet test"

The build step completed successfully but i am unable to see "tests" tab on the build.

Do i need to configure something or i need to use a different runner i.e. nunit to get the test result on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You are running your tests correctly, but the NUnit `dotnet-test-nunit` runner doesn't currently include or support the TeamCity command line option or integration. See https://github.com/nunit/dotnet-test-nunit/issues/72

TeamCity added custom code to NUnit to support their style of integration. In retrospect, the NUnit team regrets doing this and has moved it out to an extension for the main NUnit runner that is maintained by TeamCity. Because of this, we are reluctant to add the custom code back into `dotnet-test-nunit` for TeamCity when no other CI system requires it, but TeamCity is popular, so it may happen.

I don't use TeamCity so I can't help with alternatives. Do your failing tests fail the build? If so, can you live with just viewing the console output for the results of your tests?

Comment: Is it possible to run nunit3_console.exe in my instance to get the rich integration ? Please advise ?

Comment: No, sorry, nunit console can't run .NET Core tests, sorry